# $('#id').load(function(){}); not working

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="image" src="penguins.jpg"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/load.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

load.js
this is not working

```
$('#image').load(function(){
    alert('Ready');
});
```

load.js
This works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Ready');
});
```

I want to load the image first then the alert box popping up.

Comment: That's not what the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>` tag about the `<img>` tag. Because, at the time the images got loaded, jQuery won't be loaded.

You need to have a `timeout` to achieve this, because `alert` will freeze the webpage's activity and wants the user to focus the dialog. So, it won't render the image when it is called. To solve this, call the alert after a timeout.

```js
$('#image').load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Ready');
  }, 100)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="image" src="http://unsplash.it/200/300/" />
</body>

</html>
```